# How to show/hide a div on mouseover using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in this format.

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td id="divOne">div one</td>
         <td  id="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td  id="divOne">div two</td>
         <td  id="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr></div>
</table>
```

and a jquery function to show/hide a div on mouseover

```
$(function() {
$('#divOne').hover(function() { 
    $('#Details').show(); 
}, function() { 
    $('#Details').hide(); 
});
});

<div id = "Details" style="display: none;">
5555
</div>
```

I want to display the "details" div on a popup when i mouseover on each td.
The "Details" div appears when I mouse over the first row. But it is not shown when i mouseover on the second row.
I'm not sure where I go wrong.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: IDs are unique identifiers and should only be used once on a web page. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should only be one ID on the page. Change your ID's for classes and your selector for a class selector:

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td class="divOne">div one</td>
         <td class="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="divOne">div two</td>
         <td class="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

And:

```
$(function() {
$('.divOne').hover(function() { 
    $('#Details').show(); 
}, function() { 
    $('#Details').hide(); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant give same id to multiple element

**live code** is here http://jsfiddle.net/GSz5X/

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td class="divOne">div one</td>
         <td  class="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td  class="divOne">div two</td>
         <td  class="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr></div>
</table>

<div id = "Details" >
5555shdrhdrh
</div>
​

$(function() {
$('.divOne').hover(function() { 
    $('#Details').toggle(); 
});
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have repeated ids on elements, which is wrong. use classes instead, ids should be unique

```
<table>
      <tr>
         <td class="divOne">div one</td>
         <td  class="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td  class="divOne">div two</td>
         <td  class="divOne">2222</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

then change your code

```
$(function() {
  $('.divOne').hover(function() { 
    $('#Details').show(); 
  }, function() { 
    $('#Details').hide(); 
  });
});
```

this will end up (with your actual markup) with the result that your div will be shown when you hover on the table and it will be hidden when you don't

Answer (score 0):

USE class instead of ID

```
$(function() {
$('.divOne').hover(function() { 
    $('#Details').show(); 
}, function() { 
    $('#Details').hide(); 
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<td class="divOne">div one</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

```
<table id="divOne">
  <tr>
     <td>div one</td>
     <td>2222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>div two</td>
     <td>2222</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="Details" style="display: none;">
    5555
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#divOne td').hover(
            function() { $('#Details').show(); }, 
            function() { $('#Details').hide(); }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your id's to class identifiers.
See example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/A7f2p/