# How to show/hide a div on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show/hide a div on mouseover using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564481/how-to-show-hide-a-div-on-mouseover-using-jquery)

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="parent">
     foo
      <div id="child" style="display:none;">
         hidden
       </div>
</div>
```

I want to have the `child` div shown whenever someone moves their mouse over the `parent` div, and when he moves his mouse away, to hide the parent div.

However if I do this:

```
$("#parent").mouseover(toggle);
$("#parent").mouseout(toggle);
function toggle()
{
   console.log('here');
   $("#child").toggle();
}
```

Then both events seem to get called twice each time i move my mouse over the #parent div. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: I only see it happening once on mouse over, and once on mouse out: http://jsfiddle.net/6MWgy/ You sure you've not hooked the events up twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#parent").hover(
   function(){
      $("#child").show();

   },
   function(){
      $("#child").hide();
   }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about add css?

#parent #child{display:none;}

#parent:hover #child{display:block;}

with

```
 <div id="parent">
         foo
          <div id="child" >
             hidden
           </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: <div id="child">
         hidden
       </div>

You should remove display:hidden in dom

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use toggle in this case. If you always want to hide on mouseout and show on mouseover, then define them as such :)

```
$("#parent").mouseover(function() {
    $("#child").fadeIn(); // or .show() for no fading
});

$("#parent").mouseout(function() {
    $("#child").fadeOut(); // or .hide() for no fading
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use toggle function !!

Try something like this:

```
$("#parent").hover(function(){
  $("#child").show();
}, function(){
  $("#child").hide();
```

}
)

This should probably work!!

Comment: Why add a duplicate answer - upvote the original ...

Comment: sorry didn't see that !! must have been posted while i was typing my answer..Will surely upvote the above one !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Shorter:

```
$("#parent").hover(function () {
   $("#child").toggle(); 
});​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/QJDqQ/)

Note: You can subtitute [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) with [`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) or [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try .hover() like this,

```
$('#divid').hover(
function(){
 //mouseenter function
},
function(){
 //mouseleave function
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
$("#parent").mouseover(function(){
    $('#child').show();
});
$("#parent").mouseout(function(){
    $('#child').hide();
});​
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/phcwW/

Comment: Wow, I am way to slow for StackOverflow sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="parent" onmouseover="callMouseOver()" onmouseout="callMouseOut()">
     foo
      <div id="child" style="display:none;">
         hidden
       </div>
</div>
```

Js Method:

```
function callMouseOver(){
    document.getElementById("child").style.display = "inline";
}

function callMouseOut(){    
    document.getElementById("child").style.display = "none";    
}
```