# Hide/show div in ul with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let me start by saying I know this is a duplicate, however I couldn't find a solution by looking through previous answers so I was hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong with this.

This is part of a menu output by a php script:

```html
<ul id="mtk_main_menu">
<li class="mtk_topmenu" onMouseOver="showMenu('mtk_submenu_0', 'mtk_div_submenu_0');">Manager Options
    <div id="mtk_div_submenu_0">
        <ul id="mtk_submenu_0">
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Preferences</li>
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Employee Options</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

with the following as my script as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/11842992, which should show each submenu when hovering its parent container

```js
function showMenu(a,b) {
 $(a).hover(
 function(){
    $(b).show();

 },
 function(){
    $(b).hide();
 })
}
```

Javascript and CSS being my weak suits, could someone tell me where my problem is? I feel like onMouseOver doesn't work the way I would expect it to. However I am still learning to manipulate the DOM, please bear with me, thank you!

Edited to reflect missingno's suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple scenarios, i'd rather stay away from using JS

Heres how

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mtk_main_menu">
<li class="mtk_topmenu" onMouseOver="showMenu('mtk_submenu_0, mtk_div_submenu_0');">Manager Options
    <div id="mtk_div_submenu_0">
        <ul id="mtk_submenu_0">
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Preferences</li>
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Employee Options</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#mtk_main_menu:before,
#mtk_main_menu:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

#mtk_main_menu {
    *zoom:1;
}

#mtk_main_menu > li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

#mtk_main_menu > li > div {
    position:absolute;
    left:-999px;
    background:grey;
}

#mtk_main_menu > li:hover > div {
    left:0;
}
```

That will do the trick

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/7pXSw/

**Edit**

If you really want to go the JS way - heres how:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mtk_main_menu">
<li class="mtk_topmenu" onMouseOver="showMenu('mtk_submenu_0, mtk_div_submenu_0');">Manager Options
    <div id="mtk_div_submenu_0">
        <ul id="mtk_submenu_0">
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Preferences</li>
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Employee Options</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#mtk_main_menu:before,
#mtk_main_menu:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

#mtk_main_menu {
    *zoom:1;
}

#mtk_main_menu > li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

#mtk_main_menu > li > div {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    /*left:-999px;*/
    background:grey;
}

#mtk_main_menu > li:hover > div {
    /*left:0;*/
}
```

**JS**

```
function showMenu( args ) {
            var arguments = args.split(",");
            var submenuWrapper = arguments[1].replace(" ", "");
            var $subMenuWrapper = $( "#" + submenuWrapper );

            $subMenuWrapper.show();

            var $menuItem = $subMenuWrapper.closest("li");
            $menuItem.on("mouseout", function() {
                $subMenuWrapper.hide();
                $(this).off("mouseout");
            });
        }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/vnwy3/1/

Comment: This got me closer than anything else I've tried, and thank you for the js-free version, I would honestly prefer to avoid using it where possible!

Comment: True, Fiddle for the JS version attached aswel - just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the event handler with a single string parameter instead of two. Try changing

```
showMenu('mtk_submenu_0, mtk_div_submenu_0')
```

into

```
showMenu('mtk_submenu_0', 'mtk_div_submenu_0')
```

Additionally, inside your script you should use are using literal strings instead of using your parameters

```
//This looks for an element of class "a"
$("a").hover(

//This uses the contents of the `a` variable instead:
$(a).hover(
```

Finally, your function is using 'mtk_submenu_0' as a jquery selector. This searches for a class instead of an id. Change the selector to add a "#" on front or change your jquery logic to not need ids (for example, you could create selectors to search for the first div and ul descendants of the current element.

Comment: Fixed, still nothing but thanks for pointing that out! Edit: also changed parameters to literal strings, still nothing!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I find strange about your code is that the first div you mention, `mtk_submenu_0`, is inside the div you are showing / hiding, `mtk_div_submenu_0`. Once you hide the outer div, the inner div cannot be 'hovered over', thus preventing it from being shown again.

To ensure the inner div does not get hidden, try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="mtk_main_menu">
<li class="mtk_topmenu">Manager Options
    <div id="mtk_div_submenu_0">
        <ul id="mtk_submenu_0">
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Preferences</li>
            <li class="mtk_submenu">Employee Options</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mtk_topmenu').hover(
        function() {
            $('#mtk_div_submenu_0').show();
        },
        function() {
             $('#mtk_div_submenu_0').hide();
        });
});
```

Because of your line:

```
<li class="mtk_topmenu" onMouseOver="showMenu('mtk_submenu_0', 'mtk_div_submenu_0');">
```

I assumed you were looking to have the `mtk_div_submenu_0` div show / hide whenever the text `Manager Options` is moused over. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

By doing what you are doing, every time the `onMouseOver` event is triggered, you're attaching the jQuery `hover` event. Each time you're attaching another listener.

Instead, initialize your event on document ready:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tk_div_submenu_0").hover(
        function(){
            $("#mtk_submenu_0").show();
        },
        function(){
            $("#mtk_submenu_0").hide();
        })
    );
});
```

That will initialize it when the document is ready, and it will initialize it **once**.

Then just remove your onMouseOver event from the HTML.

```
<li class="mtk_topmenu">Manager Options ... </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're going the long way around the problem.  jQuery has a built in toggle method that performs the show/hide for you.  Secondly you're putting the hover call on the child element of the item you're trying to show on hover.  Here's an updated version of your code:

```
<ul id="mtk_main_menu">
    <li class="mtk_topmenu" onMouseOver="showMenu(this,'mtk_div_submenu_0');">
        Manager Options
        <div id="mtk_div_submenu_0">
            <ul id="mtk_submenu_0">
                <li class="mtk_submenu">Preferences</li>
                <li class="mtk_submenu">Employee Options</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function showMenu(a,b) {
    var divStr = '#' + a.id + " div";
    $(divStr).toggle();
}
```

I used the hover event on the `LI` element as it makes more sense in this case.

Here it is in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ecrq/